# Chrome Developer Tools, No Sensor in the console

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, emulation

I have a weird problem that I can't solve. I tried to reset the settings and reinstall Chrome but it didn't work. I'm testing a geolocated website so I want to use the sensor emulation to simulate different gps latitude and longitude. I followed the guides around the web but the tab don't show up. What's going on?
Sorry for the english but it's not my native language. I'm asking your help 'cause I'm going crazy.

You can see what I'm talking about in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` when associated with a URL that has "ads" in it strongly suggests that you have some kind of ad blocker installed in your browser.

On Google Chrome go to Settings > Extensions > AdBlock and uncheck Enable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to disable AdBlock but it didn't work.